# Handling interdependencies in maven multi-module project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cyclic-dependency

I'm been going through the `Maven Framework`. While going through multi-module projects, I read that cyclic dependency is not acceptable among the modules.
So I thought of a scenario, something like...

```
   root ----------
    - pom.xml    |
                 |
                 |--- moduleA
                 |  - pom.xml (moduleB has been added as a dependancy)
                 |
                 |--- moduleB
                    - pom.xml
```

Assume that `moduleA` has a property class `AppProperty` and a `Main` class which invokes another class `B` available in `moduleB`

`Main` class available in `moduleA` :-

```
someValue = AppProperty.get(propKey);

    //some logic
    
B mb = new B();
B.process(...);
```

Class `B` of `moduleB` :-

```
process(...) {
someOtherValue = AppProperty.get(someKey)

    // some other logic
}
```

Now `Main` will not throw any **`compile-time errors`** as its dependancies have been resolved because `moduleB` has been added as a dependancy in `moduleA'a pom.xml`. But for class `B` that is not the case as its invoking `AppProperty` class which is available in `moduleA` only. I cannot add `moduleA`'s dependancy in `moduleB`'s pom as that would lead to cyclic dependancy (if I understand it correctly).

I understand that ideally it is advised to maintain codes in an acyclic manner, but what if because of some reason removing cyclic dependancy is just not feasible? **In such a scenario, is there any way to handle cyclic dependancies without actively changing the existing code logic**?

Comment: Having cyclic dependencies can not handles by any build tool means in the end you can build your code ... that's it... you have to solve that circle... no way out ....which means change the code...or better moving things into separate module..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build a project with cyclic dependencies. You need to build B before A before B, which is kind of a contradiction.

But problems like yours are easy to solve:

- If the problem is just the class `AppProperty` or a few others, just move them from A to B.
- If you have some common classes for A and B, create a helper module C and use it as dependency in A and B.
- If A and B call each other all of the time, they should probably be just one module. So merge them to one module.